# redux persist localstorage data is vanished by reload

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I am using redux persist to store my redux state in local storage. The redux persist is working to store data in localstorage, but when I reload the page the data is gone from local storage and state. Here is link of the repo of project on which I am working https://github.com/bakarfreelancer/jccs-frontend. And The below is my reducer and store Index file.

```
//Reducer/Index.js

import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { combineReducers, compose } from "redux";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import {
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import usersReducer from "./usersReducer";
const persistConfig = {
  key: "persistroot",
  version: 1,
  storage,
};
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ users: usersReducer });
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});

export default store;

//
//
//
//Index.js

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";


import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import store from "./reducers";

let persistor = persistStore(store);
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

I want to store the redux state (which is updated after user login) in localstorage or some other storage like cookies. I checked the official documentation and I think my code is same.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not seeing anything that looks wrong here.  You've followed [the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist) correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, the problem is solved now by using redux toolkit documentation for creating my reducer. I used the createSlice method and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by using [redux toolkit documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start).
So by implementing the createSlice method for creating my reducers it works perfectly.